# how to display audio and image in the same src attribute

Tags: php

I'm trying to display some files in HTML src="" attribute. But files I want to display not only image but also audio.
How to display multiple file format in src="#"

for example the file I want to display can be sometimes an image or an audio, I would like to display;
if it is image:

**`<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment ); ?>" />`**

if it is audio:
**`<audio src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment ); ?>"></audio>`**

Answer (score 0):

You can check the filetype with the function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php

Check for the output of this function and if its "mp3" or any other auudio-format you can use the  tag and otherwise you use the  tag